# Set innerHTML of anonymous object

Tags: javascript

I want to set `innerHTML` of `style` element, but `Object.defineProperty` overrides native setter and it becomes usual property.
I know that I should split it to element creation and property assignment, but I interested in doing this without temp vars (even in anonymous block).

javascript:

```
document.body.appendChild(
Object.defineProperty(document.createElement('style'), 
                      'innerHTML', 
                      { value:'div{color:gainsboro;}' }
                     )
)
```

p.s. It`s not production code, this question asked just for curiosity.

Comment: By wanted to avoir temp var you're adding much more complexity, I'm not sure that's a good thing, also since you pass your object as parameter it is creating a temp var, inside the function so you're not gaining anything

Comment: if you just want to insert a style tag you could just do: `document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('<style>styles</style>')`, no need to create element, temp variables, or try to manipulate properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (ES 6):

```
var styleElement = Object.assign(
  document.createElement('style'), 
  {innerHTML: 'div{color:gainsboro;}'}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the attribute this way:

```
<html>
<body id="bdy">
<script>

document.getElementById("bdy").appendChild(document.createElement('style'));

document.getElementById("bdy").lastChild.innerHTML = 'div{color:gainsboro;}'
</script>


<div>
This is a div.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Two method calls, but no temp variable.

Comment: You can use `document.body` to reference `body` of html document.